# Custom Attributes for Buttons in jade

Tags: node.js, pug

Hi I'm trying to code a webpage using node.js and jade. I'm trying to add a custom attribute to a button, like in HTML:

```
<input type = "button" specialID = someSpecialID, onclick="doSomething(specialID);">
```

where someSpecialID is a value passed into the template by the node server. I've tried:

```
input(type = "button", specialID = someSpecialID, onclick = "doSomething(specialID);")
```

and:

```
input(type = "button", onclick = "doSomething(specialID);")
     specialID = someSpecialID
```

but the custom attribute doesn't seem to take. I keep getting the error that specialID is not defined.

I'm still somewhat new to node.js and jade, so I'm sorry if this is a trivial question. I'd greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly the context of execution, is someSpecialID a javascript object passed as a local? Or just some placeholder, which would be like specialID=5 in your real code?  (edit: ok, I missed the line where you say it's passed as a value, so I guess your case is the former)

If it's the former, you could use interpolation (between quotes, because I think Jade expects quotes, i.e.: `specialID="#{someSpecialID}"`)

If it's the latter, something like this would render correctly:

```
input(type="button", specialID="someSpecialID", onclick="doSomething(specialID);")
```

You should consider using a `data-special-id` attribute instead of `specialID` (custom attributes are "normalized" in HTML5 with the data- prefix).